# Error in Linkedin Company Id

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to retrieve company information in linkedin.

this is company look up info

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  api_key: YOUR_API_KEY
</script>
<script type="IN/Apply" data-companyid="10800" data-jobtitle="xxx" data-joblocation="xxxx" data-email="xxxx@gmail.com"></script>
```

Pass url :-

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/10800/
```

Error Occurred :-

```
 <error>
   <status>401</status>
   <timestamp>1388741958327</timestamp>
   <request-id>UBO9K2KHZQ</request-id>
   <error-code>0</error-code>
   <message>Unknown authentication scheme</message>
 </error>
```

So please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score -1):

I think you made an error at your script src:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
   api_key: YOUR_API_KEY
</script>
```